# NSDecimalNumber setting and getting value

Tags: ios, nsdecimalnumber

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDecimalNumber askingPrice;
```

I am trying to set the value from a textfield:

```
myManager.askingPrice = [self.askingPriceTextField.text doubleValue];
```

I get the following warning:

```
Assigning to 'NSDecimalNumber' from incompatible type 'double'
```

Also when I try getting the value like:

```
[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:myManager.askingPrice];
```

I get error:

```
 Sending 'NSDecimalNumber' to parameter of incompatible type 'double'
```

I have not worked with NSDecimalNumber before but have Google'd and seen that it is to be used when dealing with currency. Can someone point out a helper function I can use that would allow me to do what I am trying to do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `askingPrice` property in `myManager` is a `NSDecimalNumber`, a Cocoa class that wraps an object around decimal numbers. Your `askingPriceTextField.text` gives you an `NSString` that you can convert to a `float` or `double`.

So basically what you want to do is build a new `NSDecimalNumber` using the `NSString` in your text field. Here's how you can do it:

```
double askingPriceDouble = [self.askingPriceTextField.text doubleValue]; // extract a double from your text field
myManager.askingPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:askingPriceDouble]; //create an NSDecimalNumber using your previously extracted double
```

I'm using the alloc-init scheme here because you set your property to be `assign`ed. Since an `NSDecimalNumber` is an object (not a basic type like `double`), you'll either need to make sure your asking price is `retain`ed so it isn't deallocated before you need it. Another way of doing this would be to declare your property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber *askingPrice; // Do not forget the '*' sign when declaring object properties as pointers.
```

And then:

```
double askingPriceDouble = [self.askingPriceTextField.text doubleValue];
myManager.askingPrice = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:askingPriceDouble];
```

This'll work because your askingPrice property will be `retain`ed when you set it.

Also, don't forget to make sure that your text field's content can actually be converted to a double...

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
myManager.askingPrice = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.askingPriceTextField.text]
```

Comment: Oh, I'd missed the `NSString`-based constructor. :)